# ¿Para que sirve el constructor por defecto ? Poo Java

Tags: java, poo

Lo unico que pude entender es que cuando realizamos la estructura de una clase y no hacemos el constructor ,java realiza uno por defecto , pero mi pregunta es : para que sirve?, es necesario?, puedo instanciar un objeto con ese constructor aunque le falten parametros?

Comment: Asi es, siempre es necesario un constructor. Y si puedes crear un objeto con un constructor sin parametros, solo que sus atributos seran inicializados con los valores primarios, como los definiste en la declaracion o como se alteren dentro del constructor vacio.

Comment: y como lo instanciaria si no tengo sus parametros? por ejemplo si yo tengo : public class Persona {
 
 private String nombre;
 private String apellido;

 public Persona(){ }

}

public static void main (String[] args){
 
 Persona persona1 = new Persona ();
}  detro del parentesis no puedo poner nada , donde pondria los atributos del objeto? esa parte no entendi.

Comment: a que te refieres a "como lo instanciaría", en todos los lenguajes orientados a objetos (o al menos en los que yo conozco) la forma de instanciar un objeto es con la palabra clave `new` por ejemplo `Persona p = new Persona()`

Comment: a como crear un objeto con su constructor sin parametros.

Comment: creo que tienes la idea de que un objeto debe siempre tener valores pero esto no es así, ese objeto `Persona` que tu dijiste simplemente tiene como nombre nada y como apellido nada o para ser mas específico, un string vacío

Comment: los atributos del objeto puedes asignarle valores después de crear el objeto, dependiendo de la visibilidad de los atributos puedes hacerlo directamente o a través de métodos del objeto, dime ya aprendiste sobre getters y setters? me parece que al aprender eso te quedará mas claro este punto

Comment: Si vi los get y los set  .